# the name of the previous month

Tags: php, postgresql, date

How would you print the name of the previous month please?

I'm writing Drupal 7 blocks representing "the miss/mister of the last month" at my site and wonder how to do it best:

[image]

The additional difficulty is that my website is in Russian and the names are declinated.

Currently I've hardcoded month names in an array. And I don't know how to find the corrent index in that array:

```
function pref_block_view($block_name = '') {
  $MONTHS = array(
    'января',
    'февраля',
    'марта',
    'апреля',
    'мая',
    'июня',
    'июля',
    'августа',
    'сентября',
    'октября',
    'ноября',
    'декабря',
  );
  ...
if ($block_name == 'pref_mister') {
    $result = db_query("
select r.id,
        count(r.id),
        u.first_name,
        u.avatar,
        u.city
from pref_rep r, pref_users u where
        r.nice=true and
        to_char(current_timestamp - interval '1 month', 'IYYY-MM') =
        to_char(r.last_rated, 'IYYY-MM') and
        u.female=false and
        r.id=u.id
group by r.id , u.first_name, u.avatar, u.city
order by count(r.id) desc
limit 1
");
    $record = $result->fetchObject();

    return array(
      'subject' => sprintf('Фаворит %s', $MONTHS[2]),
      'content' => sprintf('
<p align="center">%s</p>
<p align="center">%s</p>
<p align="center">%u оценок</p>',
                     user_link($record),
                     user_avatar($record),
                     $record->count),
    );
  }
```

I tried

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "ru_RU");
print strftime("%B", strtotime("1/3/2003"));
# don't know how to get the prev. month date above...
```

but it has given me funny characters (probably not Russian in UTF8 - which is what I need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date("n");
```

will give you the month without leading zeroes, subtract one for your array index.

Edit: I mean subtract 2, since you'll want the previous month. Then make sure it doesn't go into negatives.

Comment: actually this will error out, you need to put quotes around "n", should be date("n"), and you don't need time() as the second parameter, as the date() function will assume the current timestamp if one is not provided.  Also this example will not work for January, as an array is not circular, so you need to account for that case.  Possibly use %12 in there (Modulus 12)

Comment: date("n", time()) - okay I will try that, thank you. Or is there a better way to find the index of the previous month?

Comment: Since `%` goes into the negatives and I'm not aware of the positive only mod function for php, I'd just go with `if (date("n",time()) == 1) {$lastMonthIndex = 11;} else {$lastMonthIndex = date("n",time()) - 2;}` assuming your month index in russian runs from 0 to 11.

Comment: Or rather use date("n") for all those checks, did not read that comment, thanks daniel.

Comment: # php -r 'echo date("n");' gives me (with PHP 5.3 at CentOS Linux 5.6) -
PHP Warning:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for 'PDT/-7.0/DST' instead in Command line code on line 1

Comment: Ok, I've set date.timezone = Europe/Berlin in /etc/php.ini - now it prints 7. Thank you

Comment: And I have an idea for the mod: instead of substracting 1, I will add: (date('n') + 11) % 12

Comment: Yup, that will work, good thinking. Though I think you'll want to add 10 to get the previous month rather than this month.

Answer (score -1):

Make a string array of months, (0 will be january, december will be 11) , get current month using a date function - if PHP has one.

Then search your string array for the index of the current month - 1  and return that

Comment: Yep, my question is which "date function" to use in PHP - in order to get the name or index of the previous month?

Comment: But I didn't -1 you, it was someone else